# Match pattern in regex expression

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm developing a generic application and I need to match a pattern that I can't solve.

The input string could be:

```
12_B 99-23_9_23
```

As you can see in the example, my problem is when I want to match this pattern "B 99-23".
The delimiter could be anything, not only underscore (ex. 12|B 99-23|9|23)

Now this is what I have...

```
Regex r = new Regex("^(?< pol>\\w+)_(?< fac>\\w+)_(?< end>\\w+)_(?< op>\\w+)");
```

I must change this part: **`(?< fac>\\w+)`**
The pattern must take everything till next delimiter ('_'), including whitespaces, numbers, characters. 
Then I'll have this result:

```
pol = 12
fac = B 99-23
end = 9
op = 23
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this pattern:

```
^(?< pol>\w+)_(?< fac>[^_]+)_(?< end>\w+)_(?< op>\w+)
```

The `[^_]` bit a [character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) which means 'match anything except an underscore'. If the delimiter is `|`, you'll have to use `\|` in your pattern, because `|` has special meaning in regular expressions (although you won't need to escape it inside a character class). Like this:

```
^(?< pol>\w+)\|(?< fac>[^|]+)\|(?< end>\w+)\|(?< op>\w+)
```

On a side note, I find it's much easier to use verbatim strings when specifying a regular expression pattern because you won't have to type in so many escape sequences:

```
new Regex(@"^(?< pol>\w+)\|(?< fac>[^|]+)\|(?< end>\w+)\|(?< op>\w+)");
```

---

However, in this case, you might be better off just using [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx):

```
var result = input.Split(new char[] { '_' }, 4);
// result[0] = 12
// result[1] = B 99-23
// result[2] = 9
// result[3] = 23
```

Comment: Thank you!
But this won't work whit this example... 
12|B 99-23|9|23

It must match till next delimitter. In the example above will be like: ^(?< pol>\w+)|(?< fac>)|(?< end>\w+)|(?< op>\w+)

Sorry if I don't explain it very good

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a pattern that will work for `|` characters. You stated, "[the] delimiter could be anything," but that doesn't make much sense. What delimiters are you expecting? Do you need to handle mixed delimiters? How should `12|B 99_23|9|23` be matched?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Part of the problem is that `\w` also includes all letter a-z, all number 0-9, and the underbar `_`. So if your input text could use a `_` delimiter then expression matching `\w+` will get confused

Because you have a requirement to allow underbars as a delimiter I suggest instead of using the short hand `\w` that you instead define the character class you'd like for both the desired text and the delimiters.

- `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` will match one or more alphebetical or numbers in any order
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` this is a negated character class, and will match any character which is not alphebetical or numbers

This regex will match all values, and will allow a wide range of delimiters.

`^(?<pol>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9](?<fac>[0-9a-zA-Z]+\s[0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9](?<end>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9](?<op>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)`

[image]

## Groups

To match the `fac` group I'm assuming the field will be in the format: Letter Space Numbers Hyphen Numbers.

- Group 0 will get the entire matched string
- The named groups will be created, however in the image 1=pol, 2=fac, 3=end, and 4=op. Sorry for the confusion the drawing software doesn't handle named capture groups.

## C# Code Example:

Input text

```
12_B 99-23_9_23
11_a 11-11_1_11
22|b 22-22|2|22
33-c 33-33-3-33
44,d 44-44,4,44
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"^(?<pol>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9](?<fac>[0-9a-zA-Z]+\s[0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9](?<end>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9](?<op>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Matches

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12_B 99-23_9_23
            [1] => 11_a 11-11_1_11
            [2] => 22|b 22-22|2|22
            [3] => 33-c 33-33-3-33
            [4] => 44,d 44-44,4,44
        )

    [pol] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 22
            [3] => 33
            [4] => 44
        )


    [fac] => Array
        (
            [0] => B 99-23
            [1] => a 11-11
            [2] => b 22-22
            [3] => c 33-33
            [4] => d 44-44
        )


    [end] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
        )


    [op] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 22
            [3] => 33
            [4] => 44
        )


)
```